# Separating classes in different files in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I am a beginner trying to build a simple game. For convenience I want to separate my classes (about six of them) into separate files. These classes *depend on and use each other*, with the Game() class being the 'main' class.

However, the classes seem to either not be able to find each other, or at least not to call each other. I tried two things:

1. In each file, import all the other classes

```
import game
import player
import powerup
```

etc. 
However, when calling methods (e.g. `player.move()` or `game.reset()`), I receive this error: 
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

2. This made me think that I should import only the class inside the file, so I tried this:

```
from game import game
from player import player
from powerup import powerup
```

This does not work and gives this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'player' from 'player' (C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\ballgame\player.py)`

To be clear, every file is named after the class and contains only one class, e.g. class Player() in file player.py
All files are in one folder without subfolders. I also made an empty **init**.py because I read that this is required.

File structure:

```
folder ballgame
--- __init___.py
---game.py
---player.py
---powerup.py
```

every file looks like this:

```
import game
import player
import [all other classes]

Class()
    methods()
```

How should I structure the classes in order to make it work? And should I import each class into each file?

Comment: So, `from player import Player` then…?

Comment: That does not seem to work, gives the same error.

Comment: Also, I'm new to stack overflow. Is this not the type of questions I am supposed to ask? Because of the downvotes.

Comment: So try `from .player import Player`

Comment: I see this is the markup of Stackoverflow, it is named double underscore _ _init_ _.py

Comment: No because it is the same folder, not a subfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no problem with this: from player import **Player** <<-- capitalize here
are you sure that no typo or some missing capital letter you write it small.

I think that classes usually start with big letter and you write it samll are you sure it's really small in the file of the class.

make sure that name of the file and name of class exactly the same as you import

Comment: This seems to only work if I remove the import statements in the other files. However, I need to import all the classes in all the files because they depend on each other.

Comment: How do all depend on all, if 'a' depend on 'b' and 'b' depends on 'a', who will work first and how?

Comment: Yes I figured the same thing, they can not cross reference and they do not need to. I found the solution, thank you all!